Derivative of $x^T \cdot A \cdot x$ with diagonal $A$
I know that
$
\frac{d x^T \cdot A \cdot x}{dA} = x \cdot x^T
$
from the Matrix cookbook
$$\frac{\partial a^TXb}{\partial X}=ab^T$$
but what is the derivative if $A$ is a diagonal matrix?
I am confused because the non-diagonal elements are $0$ and that would be sort of a derivative of a constant.
Also, I would like to have to calculate as few values as possible, so I am interested in the size of the result - the smaller, the better my time complexity.
Background: I want to optimize $A$ and thus I need to calculate the gradient for gradient descent.

Please, avoid the use of images. Use MathJax to type your questions. You should use it also in the title.

To enforce the diagonal constraint, take the Hadamard product of the Cookbook result with the identity matrix, i.e. $,I\odot\left(x\cdot x^T\right).;$ Setting $,X=\operatorname{Diag}(x),$ this can be simplified to $X^2$

It doesn't matter if $A$ is a diagonal matrix or not, because under small perturbation, the off diagonal elements may still be nonzero. This is like the function $f(x)=2x$ has nonzero derivative $2$ even when $x=0, f(0)=0$.
Here we also have $\frac{\partial a^TXb}{\partial X}=a^Tb$ doesn't depend on $X$. This is not surprising, as $X\mapsto a^TXb$ is a linear function of $X$.
However, if you mean to optimize in the subspace of diagonal matrices, then the off diagonal elements of $a^Tb$ are meaningless, as the perturbation of these shall be $0$ in each step of gradient descent, so we don't have to calculate them. That is, the gradient is simply $(a_1b_1, a_2b_2, \cdots, a_nb_n)$.

Yes, I mean to optimize the subspace of diagonal matrices :-). As I wrote, I optimize for A and A is a diagonal matrix.

If $a^T X b = \sum_{ij} x_{ij} a_i b_j $, then the partial derivative wrt. $x_{ij}$ of this is $a_i b_j$, and collecting these into a matrix, we get $ab^T$. In case of a diagonal matrix, the only variables are $x_{ii}$, so we can collect these and then the relevant partial derivatives, $a_i b_i$, into a vector. This vector is the (pointwise or) Hadamard-product of $a$ and $b$, that is, $a \odot b$, which is the same as the diagonal of the matrix $ab^T$.
